# How can an ContextCustomizer access Springs environment properties?

Tags: java, spring

I am implementing a custom Spring context customizer, as I have to perform some operations during startup of the application. The result of the operation is need to configure the datasource I need in my application.

My problem is now, that I need for those operations access to my configuration properties (from application.yaml), as they are the base for my operations.

My, simplified, implementation looks currently like this. Nothing special.

```java
public class MyContextCustomizerFactory
  implements ContextCustomizerFactory {
  @Target(TYPE) @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Documented @Inherited
  public @interface EnabledPostgresTestContainer {
  }

  @Override
  public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(Class<?> c,
                                                   List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> a) {
  }

  static class MyContextCustomizer implements ContextCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customizeContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext c, 
                                     MergedContextConfiguration mc) {
    }
  }
}
```

Of is there an alternatvie approach. Using Springs `DynamicPropertySource` is currently not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `ContextCustomizerFactory` is what you are looking for, because you are talking about "application" but `ContextCustomizerFactory` is designed for running tests, anyway...

What exactly has confused you?

```java
public class MyContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

    @Override
    public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(Class<?> testClass, List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
        return new MyContextCustomizer();
    }

}
```

```java
public class MyContextCustomizer implements ContextCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customizeContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = context.getEnvironment();

        // reading properties
        String applicationName = environment.getProperty("application.name");

        // enriching properties
        Properties jdbcProperties = new Properties();
        jdbcProperties.put("spring.datasource.url", "jdbc://....");
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new PropertiesPropertySource("customizerProperties", jdbcProperties)
        );
    }
}
```

---

UPD.

If the goal is to modify env/properties after `Spring` has parsed `@Configuration` classes with `@PropertySource` we may use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, below are some examples from spring:

- [EmbeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration.java) - very similar to what TC needs
- [PropertySourceOrderingPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.5.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java#L265) - reorders property sources
- [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.java)

Comment: Yes, it is read from `application.properties`. Maybe I oversimplified my question.

My setup contains a profile, which reads properties from for a different file called `local-setup.properties`. Values from this file are available in my tests, but they are not available in the context customizer. 

So resolving profile related properties must happen later. I guess.

Comment: Do you expect to read contents of `@TestPropertySource`?

Comment: No, I have a dedicated class with a `@Profile`, a `@Configuration`, and several `@PropertySource` annotations.

Comment: @Oliver it seems that `ContextCustomizer` is not an option and you actually need `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, please check upd.

Comment: I ended by implementing a `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, but even it is not able to access the property values I defined. It works fine, if I put it properties I have to process in the standard `application.properties`. So I either have to redesign my property file layout or to find the right place, there I can hook in. I will contact the Spring community via Gitter.